# If at least one ocurrence of that echo this

Tags: php, mysql, count, html-heading

I am writing a resume script and I need the heading "Reference" to be inserted if a mysql query finds at least one occurence of the current job_id in the table "references", how would I be able to that?

Comment: if you have an array, you can use the function count, ie, $rows=count($array);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can determine the number of rows returned by a query with [`mysql_num_rows()`](http://php.net/mysql_num_rows) or [`$mysqli_result->num_rows`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php) if you're using MySQLi. Which I recommend.

Then it's a simple `if`:

```
if ($result->num_rows) {
  echo 'References';
  // do more stuff...
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I ended up using this. Here is the final code
    `$query01  = "SELECT * FROM Referanser RIGHT JOIN Jobref ON  Referanser.id = Jobref.ref_id WHERE job_id = '$jobbid' ORDER BY Referanser.id DESC";
    $result01 = mysql_query($query01);
    $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result01);
    if ($num_rows >= 1) { echo "<p class=\"reftittel\">Referanser</p>"; }`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$mysqli->num_rows`, see the sample code below.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "password", "database");
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}


$num_references = 0

$res = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM references");
$num_references = $res->num_rows;

if ($num_references > 0) {
  echo "<h1>Reference</h1>"
}
```